# Popup randomly takes forever to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

So we have a page with a popup using ajax ModalPopupExtender. Most of the time the popup loads just fine, but randomly it will take forever to load. I have stepped through the code and it steps through just fine, but it slows down when it posts back to the page. Is there some setting in IE 9 or something like that that could be causing this? I would post code, but its very long and I'm fairly confident it's not the code.

Comment: `slows down when it posts back` could be network latency, but it's pretty much impossible to tell without more information. I would probably start by setting up a test that makes that postback call a bunch of times to see if it slows down consistently.

Comment: It's not consistent. What we have is a button in a datagrid that when clicked launches a popup where you can edit information. The popup could load 10 times in a row just fine and then be slow the 11th time and then fast again the 12th. It really does seem to be random.

Comment: Individually, you're right, that's not consistent. Trying many tests over a longer time period may help you uncover something.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the popup in the link below. This will not have any post back issues. we have tested it with various browsers.

http://atldunia.com/youtube/Zpopup.aspx